# postgresql: syntax error at or near "IF" why?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This function is a trigger that restricts grouping by series type when grouping posts.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION post_is_publish() 
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $body$
    BEGIN
        WITH
            psid AS (
                SELECT
                    id
                FROM
                    post_series
                WHERE
                    id = NEW.post_series_id
            )
            ,p AS (
                SELECT
                    posting_type
                FROM
                    posts
                WHERE
                    id = (SELECT id FROM psid)
            )
        IF (SELECT posting_type FROM p) = '0' THEN
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    END;
$body$
;
CREATE TRIGGER post_is_publish BEFORE INSERT ON post_groups
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION post_is_publish();
```

The error is as the title says.
Functions with similar syntax work, so I don't understand why this function gives an error.

version: postgresql15

・bracketed`IF ((SELECT posting_type FROM p) = '0')  THEN`
・aliased and unaliased

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the query results. You probably want a FOR loop and a record variable

Comment: Where is your source to say *functions with similar syntax work*? If they do a `SELECT` query followed by an `IF`, I suggest you double-check where exactly the `;` between them is written.

Comment: `WITH` must part of a `SELECT` statement. Run the two queries as idependent statements and store the result in variables.

Comment: `IF` is PL/pgSQL. But your query is pure SQL. You can't mix both languages as you like.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but when I created two functions that divided the language into SQL and PLPGSQL, and separated the type acquisition and conditional branching, the error disappeared.first of all thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to split the function, you just need to assign the value of `posting_type` to a variable and then test that variable. I made assumption that `posting_type` is a string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION post_is_publish() 
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $body$
    DECLARE
        p_type varchar;
    BEGIN
        WITH
            psid AS (
                SELECT
                    id
                FROM
                    post_series
                WHERE
                    id = NEW.post_series_id
            )
            ,p AS (
                SELECT
                    posting_type
                FROM
                    posts
                WHERE
                    id = (SELECT id FROM psid)
            )
        SELECT posting_type INTO p_type FROM p;

        IF p_type = '0' THEN
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    END;
$body$
;
CREATE TRIGGER post_is_publish BEFORE INSERT ON post_groups
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION post_is_publish();
```

Comment: Now I know why I tried to do this and failed.Because I was trying to use `INTO` inside `WITH`.

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions that divided the language into SQL and PLPGSQL, and separated the type acquisition and conditional branching, the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a separate `IF` block; you can do it all in a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION post_is_publish() 
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $body$
DECLARE result RECORD;
BEGIN
WITH psid AS (
    SELECT id
    FROM post_series
    WHERE id = NEW.post_series_id
), p AS (
    SELECT posting_type
    FROM posts
    WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM psid)
)
SELECT
   MAX(CASE
        WHEN posting_type = '0' THEN NEW
        ELSE NULL END) INTO result
FROM p;
RETURN result;
END;
$body$
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bm8laCW8).

Not sure if you want MAX, MIN or something else, but you can adjust accordingly.

Note also the more compact formatting that increases readability.

Comment: Exactly how is this going to work. 1) You will get the error: *ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.* 2) If you correct 1)  you will get: *ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I rushed it. got something that compiles - see live demo link.

Comment: That is not going to work either you will get error like: *ERROR:  returned row structure does not match the structure of the triggering table*. In other words the function is created, but it will fail on use.